# Event monitoring no email received

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I am following the tutorial https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Event_monitoring .
for event monitoring. I have created an event rule for course creation and admin has subscribed for the event. But when the course creator creates a course no email is received to admin email. Please help.

Comment: What is your notification threshold?

Comment: Notification threshold is 1 in 1 minute.